# How to package JARs in Spark (Scala) outside of a project?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to setup Spark (Scala) and Jupyter notebook. The [setup is easy](https://github.com/Valassis-Digital-Media/spylon-kernel) except when you want to add things like database drivers, particularly redshift in my case, which is a complicated web of JAR interdependences which I have spent a day trying to get right.

I also installed spark localy (Ubuntu 18.04) and have the same problem, finding the `/jar` folder and then figuring out which versions I drivers, libs etc I need to work with the ones that come with it.

All this to get spark in a Jupyter notebook connecting to redshift :@

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to use Scala for Spark, it's better to setup/use Zeppelin notebook environment instead of Jupyter. And once you have Zeppelin working, create a new notebook and in an empty cell you can use the %sh magic command to run Unix style commands (like sudo apt-get ) to install any additional libraries you'll need.

Comment: This still doesn't explain how I would install a Redshift JDBC connector (and all its dependencies). HOW do you manage the dependencies of the Spark instillation?

Comment: Try this: https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2016/02/08/setting-up-your-analytics-stack-with-jupyter-notebook-aws-redshift/

Note, I don't have a Redshift instance to connect to, so I haven't tried these steps myself but by the looks of it, the author has listed the steps in an easy to follow guide format and that should get you going. If you run into any specific problems, you can post more details here.

Comment: Yeah, thats Jupyter notebooks to Redshift via `psycopg2`, ya easy BUT the question is about connecting Spark to Redshift NOT the same thing. Slow down. Read the question.

Comment: Ah I see what you're after! You want to connect to Redshift via Spark from within a Jupyter notebook environment.

First, download the appropriate Redshift driver jar from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html. Save it to whatever path you deem appropriate. Next, launch Jupyter Notebook using the command/options:-

`bin/pyspark --driver-class-path /path_to_redshift_driver.jar --jars /path_to_redshift_driver.jar`

Finally, use the instructions in this link to connect:-
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#usage